# Create raster from XYZ

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a data set consisting of XYZ data. The dimensions are 5587 rows by 3 columns.

I try to use rasterFromXYZ from the raster package but I get the following error:

> Error in rasterFromXYZ(DATA) : x cell sizes are not regular

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing example data making it hard to help you out. What the message means is that your data does not appear to be regularly spaced.

Instead of `rasterFromXYZ` you can use `rasterize` in which case you specify the required geometry and then transfer the values to it.

Depending on your goals, you may also use `interpolate`